# Find the the maximum value of $|z|$ i.e. $|z|_{\textrm{max}}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> If $$\left|z-\frac{4}{z}\right|=2$$ where $z$ is a complex number, find the maximum possible value of $|z|$ i.e. $|z|_{\textrm{max}}$

My attempt:

$$\left|z-\frac{4}{z}\right|=2\le|z|+\frac{4}{|z|}\implies$$
$$2\le\frac{|z|^2+4}{|z|}\implies$$
$$|z|^2-2|z|+4\ge0\:\:-(1)$$

we know that, $|z|$ is a real number so the above quadratic is an equation in real numbers. But since its $\Delta\lt0$ it cannot be $\ge0$. Hence, a contradiction occurs which $\implies$ there exists no $|z|$ satisfying $(1)$. Consequently there exists no $z$. But I believe that there is some flaw in my solution.

Also I would like to know different approaches for solving this problem, maybe like calculus.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: (1) holds for all $z$ so it is not useful. $(|z|-1)^{2}+3 \geq 0+3>0$ for all $z$.

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong. Consider $|z| = 5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2 \geq |z|-\frac 4 {|z|}$. This gives  $|z|^{2}-2|z|-4 \leq 0$  So $|z| \leq 1+\sqrt 5$. I will let you check that  $z=1+\sqrt 5$ satisfies the given equation. Hence, the maximum  value of $|z|$ is $1+\sqrt 5$.

Comment: so the answer is $1+\sqrt5+0\cdot i$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @EveryonesaysFU

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative we have

$$\left|z-\frac{4}{z}\right|^2=\left(z-\frac{4}{z}\right)\left(\bar z-\frac{4}{\bar z}\right)=|z|^2-4\left(\frac{z}{\bar z}+\frac{\bar z}{z}\right)+\frac{16}{|z|^2}=4$$

$$\iff|z|^4-12|z|^2+16=0 \implies |z|_{\text{max}}=1+\sqrt 5$$

using that $\frac{z}{\bar z}+\frac{\bar z}{z}=2$.

Comment: $$|z|^2-4\left(\frac{z}{\bar z}+\frac{\bar z}{z}\right)+\frac{16}{|z|^2}=4$$ will reduce to $$|z|^4-8z^2+16=4|z|^2$$ how that **mod** sign came $8z^2?$

Comment: pls expand and elaborate

Comment: @EveryonesaysFU it will not simplify to $z^2$, we should get $2|z|^2\cos(2\theta)$ and then we can use the fact that $\cos(2\theta)≤1$

Comment: @EveryonesaysFU The point is that $\frac{z}{\bar z}+\frac{\bar z}{z}=2$ then multiply by $|z|^2$.

Comment: can you pls tell how the value is $2$

Comment: can we apply am gm here?

Comment: We have that $w+\bar w = 2\Re(w)$ and $\frac{z}{\bar z}=\bar{\left(\frac{\bar z}{z}\right)}$ and $\left|{\frac{\bar z}{z}}\right|=1$.

Comment: thanks a lot sir